# Make UIWebView part of UITableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiwebview

I need to make UI like following:

In response to a HTTPRequest, I am getting JSON response.
Title & Some HTML Content.

I fill UITableViewCell with the title i get in response.
Now, I need to display the HTML Content in a dropdown manner, with UITableViewCell. **Means, on tapping on cell It appears below the cell (or say, in the cell) and tapping again will make it disappear.**

I am thinking of making UIWebView, a part of UITableViewCell. Any guidance on how to achive that.

And also, Is there any better way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked, **"And also, Is there any better way to perform this?"**

Not **better** I can say, but
In my case, I did it using different approach.
on `didSelectRowAtIndexpath:` I set up new UIWebView and showed the HTML content in it.

I really searched the web for setting the height of UIWebView dynamically, as per the content I am getting through WebResponse. But, I didn't found anything useful, really.

Answer (score 1):

You can try dynamically inserting and removing custom cell which holds UIWebView below cell you select on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. But I strongly suggest you find a way to convert HTML into string (NSAttributedString, for example) and show a label. UIWebView is known for killing performance.